# Linq To Entity :: What the following code is doing?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am running this query but i am unsure of what is it fetching ?

```
var sm = pe.Categories.Include("ParentCategory").Where(c => c.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Electronics");
```

**What will the variable *sm* have ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - You need to remove the `Include` statement. Linq-to-Entities will allow you to access the properties of the entity without having to include them

```
var sm = pe.Categories
           .Where(c => c.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Electronics");
```

- `sm` will be an `IQueryable` of type Category
- It will contain Categories where its ParentCategory CategoryName is "Electronics"
- Each cateogry will have its ParentCategory preloaded for you

Comment: Thanks.....but i don't want the ParentCategory preloaded. I just want the categories whose Parent is "Electronics". What should i do then ??

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay - I updated the answer. You just need to remove the Include statement

Comment: Thanks mate, I am actually bit alien to this type of syntax. Is this what they call Linq Method syntax.

Comment: Yeah this is Method syntax, Query syntax would be: var sm = from c in pe.Categories where c.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Electronics" select c;

Answer (score 1):

```
var sm = pe.Categories
           .Where(c => c.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Electronics");
```

This should work as you expect. Adding Include preloads the specified entity.

Comment: hmm....dats what...I was bit confused about include, didnt wanted to have the ParentCategory Preloaded :-) .. Thanks